# Change Url Routing Asp to PHP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hi I want to change Url when load page from aspx to PHP in ASP.NET Webform

```
My-website.com/Login.aspx
Change 
My-website.com/Login.php
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @user743414 nothing